# Custom QML module not found

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I have a QML application. I have created my own QML module. called `MyCustomModule`. The module has the appropriate `qmldir` file, which is registered to the corresponding `my_custom_module.qrc` file. I also add the import path with `addImportPath("qrc:///my_custom_module");` on application startup in C++. I am using CMake instead of QMake.

Where ever I import `MyCustomModule` QtCreator tells me `QML module not found`, but when I build the application builds without any issues and runs.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You better should provide some source code instead of explaining it.

Comment: I think in this case source code would have been just a dead end and would have just deflect the attention from the real issue. As I said the code is fine since it builds and runs. On the other hand I have found the solution adding it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My issue was that I was missing `QML_IMPORT_PATH` from my CMake file. Example:

```
# Make Qt Creator aware of where the QML modules live
set (_QML_IMPORT_PATHS "")

## Add new module paths here.
list (APPEND _QML_IMPORT_PATHS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/your/module)

set (
    QML_IMPORT_PATH
    ${_QML_IMPORT_PATHS}
    CACHE
    STRING
    "Path used to locate CMake modules by Qt Creator"
    FORCE
)
```

One important side note is that the `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/your/module` should point to the folder where the module lives and not to the module folder itself. So if you have a path like this:
`/path/to/your/module/MyCustomModule`, the CMake should contain the path `/path/to/your/module`.

Comment: For an improved way to set `QML_IMPORT_PATH` in the CMake makefile, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38266179).