# QML module not found when using KDE Kirigami

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator, kde-plasma

So I decided to use KDE Kirigami UI framework in my app so I followed the instructions [here](https://api.kde.org/frameworks/kirigami/html/index.html). I cloned the repo in my app directory and then added it with a simple `include(kirigami/kirigami.pri)` in my project file.

Now this works, however the problem I encountered is that in QML there is always the error: `QML module not found` when I import the plugin (`import org.kde.kirigami 2.9`). The project still compiles and runs just fine and I am able to use the UI components I need, however the major issue is that code completion and syntax highlighting for the Kirigami plugin do not work.

A similar question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352930/qt5-qml-module-is-not-installed), I have tried all the suggestions in the answers of that thread but none of them worked:

- I imported `QQmlEngine::addImportPath` the `kirigami/src/controls` folders using absolute and relative paths. I also tried with `qrc:/`.
- I added a `QML_IMPORT_PATH += $$PWD/kirigami/src/controls $$PWD/kirigami` line to my project file.

Answer (score 1):

When you mouse over the "module org.kde.kirigami not found" error marker in a QML file, the popup tells you that Qt Creator is looking in `QML_IMPORT_PATH` for these files. It also tells you how to set this.

By adding `QML_IMPORT_PATH += …` to your project file, you have set it for a `qmake` based build process. However, Kirigami projects usually use CMake, and that might be the reason why your previous attempts did not work out.

To set `QML_IMPORT_PATH` for a CMake based build system, you would open the `CMakeLists.txt` file from the root of your project tree and add the following section on top:

```
# ------------------------- BEGIN: lists to maintain manually -------------------------

# Directories where Qt Creator can find QML files of Kirigami etc. on your system.
#   (This setting is cached in variable QML_IMPORT_DIR, see below. Delete
#   ${BUIL_DIR}/CMakeCache.txt to make make changes here effective.)
list(APPEND QML_DIRS "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml")

# ------------------------- END: lists to maintain manually -------------------------


# Tell Qt Creator where to find QML files.
#   (The build process will work without this, but no code completion etc..)
set(
    QML_IMPORT_PATH "${QML_DIRS}"
    CACHE STRING "Qt Creator 4.1 extra qml import paths"
)
```

Of course, adapt it to the correct directory for your system. On a Debian / Ubuntu based system, the following will determine the directory containing Kirigami QML files installed from the repositories:

```
dpkg -L qml-module-org-kde-kirigami2 | grep "\.qml"
```

**Source:** [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38266179) on StackOverflow

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I forgot to answer this question myself as this has been solved in the [Qt forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/104861/how-to-use-kde-frameworks-with-qt-creator/8).